# Transform $.show() to css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I got this css:

```
#pop {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100vw;
        height: 100vh;
        background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
        z-index: 10;
        display: none;
        }
```

Until now, in order to show this #pop div I used `$("#pop").show(450);`
How can I do it more "Cheaply" with css? I'd like to keep the same fade in effect $.show(ms) provides, not just display it.

Comment: Remove the `display: none;` ?

Comment: jquery show() is the equivalent of display:block or whatever display property the element originally had.  change display:none to display: block

Comment: @RobertWade not entirely accurate when a delay time is given. It fades in element

Comment: show(ms), provides a fade in effect.

Comment: My bad. Title of your post omits the fact that you wanted to show the transition. your line about keeping the fade in effect was added in your edit after i made my comment.  What is it that triggers the show currently?  Is there some sort of user input?  Or is this just onload?

Comment: @RobertWade Thanks for your help. it's an onclick.

Comment: Since you wanted something with less weight, I added an example using vanilla js in my answer below.  No jquery required to do this if you really want to shed weight in your application you don't need it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well you can create animation and switch class on element something like:

```
$('#pop').addClass('show');
```

and you would need css something like this:

```
 #pop {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
  z-index: 10;
  display: block;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
}
#pop.show {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: 1.45s all;
}
```

As far as I know display property doesn't support transitions so you will need to do it with opacity. You could potentially put both classes on same element to simulate feel of element becoming visible on page load.

Here's update with fiddle, you need to use visibility property:
https://fiddle.jshell.net/6jwfz608/

Comment: sorry can you try again, it should work fine I had issues in code

Comment: great answer, also, if you don't like the fade effect that opacity does, you can experiment with changing positioning too.  I did not know that display straight up doesn't work with transitions though. that helps me in a game

Answer (score 2):

you can use JS to toggle classes using "className" and use transition in the CSS

CSS

```
.pop_hidden {
    transition:all 450ms;

    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: -101vw;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    z-index: 10;
    display: none;
}
.pop_shown {
        transition:all 450ms;

        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100vw;
        height: 100vh;
        background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
        z-index: 10;
        display: none;
    }
```

(css edit) i got rid of display and changed it to moving the div from out of frame going right.

JS

```
document.getElementById('pop').className = 'pop_hidden';//to load the hidden div you can use id too
setTimeout(() => {
     document.getElementById('pop').className = 'pop_shown';
}, 20);///adjustable delay if needed(ex: set to var in game loop)
```

Edit: my opinion on using CSS transition in combination with setting classNames.  It's easy and fun to do.   For a fading effect, toggle opacity. for and slide effect, toggle positions, there are tons of creative ways to change your elements.  And since the naming of classes is completely arbitrary, you can have multiple classes to switch to. Also, i switched it to class out of habit(SORRY).  But it should not matter, you can toggle id's the same way.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example showing onclick functionality and handled with Vanilla Javascript and no Jquery, since you wanted something less weighty.

```js
document.getElementById('showBill').addEventListener('click', function () {
  var bill = document.getElementById('bill');
  if (bill.classList.contains('hide')) {
   bill.classList.remove('hide');
  } else {
   bill.classList.add('hide');
  }
});
```

```css
img {
   opacity: 1;
   transition: opacity 3s ease-in-out;
   -moz-transition: opacity 3s ease-in-out;
   -webkit-transition: opacity 3s ease-in-out;
}
img.hide {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<button id='showBill'>Show Bill</button>
<br/>
<img src='http://fillmurray.com/300/300' class='hide' id='bill' />
```